# Reading a local json file

Tags: javascript, json, html, local, offline

I'm developing an **offline** "application", based on **HTML5**. For my purpose I need to read a **local** json file but, as I experienced and as I read, through javascript this option is unavailable because of security policies.

Have you any idea about how to bypass the problem? Every hint is well accepted.

Answer (score 1):

That's not entirely true.

Chrome has some security restrictions that prevent local JSON being read by default; however Firefox for example works fine out of the box.

There are [some workarounds for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS), however the fixes usually rely on modifying settings on the clients machine.

Comment: Isn't there an unique solution for all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an "offline application" than why do you want to use webtools like a browser (and not JavaFX, Windows, ...).

You can say that you want to use the browser as a client for your purposes (or you are webdeveloper). Then you can use a local server to serve you "offline". Simple to start most of them not even to install or needed a large environment.

There are a plenty of local server and they are very powerfull to do anything you want. Search the web for web servers, languages or frameworks like: play framework, nodejs and many many more. 
After using such a server you can access any local service or local files.

This is how webdevelopers work on their local machines and transfering that to the target server afterwards.